# Django / Mezzanine: Staff users can't log in to admin

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin, mezzanine

Using Django 1.8 and Mezzanine 4.0 and Python 3, if I assign a user as staff, I find they don't have permission to log into the admin pages of my site. They can if I assign them as superuser (which I don't want to do). My `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is set up properly and the same domain appears in the "Site permissions" list for the users.

I've searched online for others who have experienced this but the only thread I found was someone who found that the problem mysteriously resolved itself when they reinstalled their entire stack (which I don't want to do either!)

Can anyone shed any light?

Comment: Did you set the correct domain under "Site permissions"?

Comment: I do... my situation seems to be the same as [this one](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1366) and although I still have the duplicate "Site permissions" boxes, I can get my staff users to log in by following [this advice from another SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434024/how-to-set-the-permissions-for-admins-of-django-mezzanine-sites). Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you open up the settings for the user you can select the site that you want it to have access to. Check out this for further information: [How to set the permissions for admins of Django/Mezzanine sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33434024/how-to-set-the-permissions-for-admins-of-django-mezzanine-sites)

Comment: This is the link I mention in my comment above. I'm not sure why clicking on the site should be necessary if it already appears in the "Site permissions" box. This may be a UI bug, I suspect.

Comment: Hmm, I now tried it and it doesn't work for me either. This is most likely a bug.